# Parallel API calls using angular

Tags: angular, parallel-processing

Assume that I have a REST service/API(/employee/updateDetails/) to be invoked by **angular** UI.

I have a table with multiple rows with a provision of checkbox for each row to select, I would like to have a parallel API calling for the selected rows from UI to the same service.

I would like to invoke them on a button click for selected rows, response of each row should get updated back to UI as soon as service completed for particular row?

Is there any better solutions for this, please do suggest me.

Comment: what have you tried? where are you stuck?

Comment: I have not tried anything for now as a beginner to angular,  after looing for few documentations get to know that forkJoin or FlatMap can be used. But I was not clear to them, so thought of getting best solutions

Comment: As a beginner, You don't need to do such things. Go through this first - https://angular.io/docs then you can make such api calls.